# How to read TextEdit Document with java scanner on mac

Tags: java

I have these Quark Files that I am trying to read in eclipse because I am looking for a certain line but the scanner will only read the first line.

```
    String fileName = "/Users/davidheffernan/Downloads/AWM-7-6";
    readFileByLine(fileName);
```

.

```
   public static void readFileByLine(String fileName) {
      try {
       File file = new File(fileName);
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
       //scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
       }
       scanner.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } 
     }
```

I know this works with a simple textfile but this is not working with the file I am using. Here is a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0tQJKIygtzcklLeWNlTnhreTA/view?usp=sharing
I have to do this with a 1,000 docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file you provided is not a plain text file, it is a binary file. Therefore using Scanner (or any other line oriented file reader) will not work.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347327/trying-to-read-binary-file-as-text-but-scanner-stops-at-first-line) for more details.